# How to copy an active excel sheet and paste it to the body of my Gmail using python

Tags: python, excel

Hi good day my friends,

I have a question regarding copy paste some excel stuff to email body
In the previous stage, have successfully done the data processing
I have processed the excel file and it looks like this in my Excel File: [My excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seAcY.jpg)

And what come next is I want to copy the active cells to the body of the email using gmail for reporting purpose like this [Email reporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEOGF.jpg)

is anybody here knows how to do execute it properly? I can only add the excel attachment already but unable to add this table formatting to the email body

every help and suggestion is really appreciated

Thank you

Comment: the code that answer your question contain two main parts: first the one that extract the selected cells and save the result as image and second part create a Gmail message and attach the extracted image. for the second part see the Gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#python

Comment: Okay thanks i got the idea.. I have successfully saved the active cells in the sheet into '.png'. And when i want to embed that png file into the html body email, i noticed that the image contains CID and read another article saying:

"The problem with CID embedded images is that they don’t always display properly in email clients. The rule of thumb I use is that CID embedding will work fine in the majority of desktop email clients, but most likely not at all in web-based email clients such as Gmail or Yahoo! Mail."

Comment: since you completed the first part, should I post the answer to the second part? is that okay with you

Comment: @Thulfiqar I have done the entire part!! thanks a lot brother.. But i have one question.. Once I tried to send the email that contains the attachment and also the embedded image in the body email into 2 different gmail account. 
One gmail received it in its inbox, another one received it in their spam.
Do we have a certain way to ensure it all go to the recipient inbox?

Comment: are the two accounts belong to the same service provider (i.e. Gmail) because I think this related to the spam filtration mechanism. However, I think this problem should be fixed by the email receiver.

Comment: are the two accounts belong to the same service provider (i.e. Gmail) because I think this related to the spam filtration mechanism. However, I think this problem should be fixed by the email receiver.

Comment: yes, both are gmail, so we can do nothing from our side? and I also noticed that the embedded image was shown in the desktop browser, but not in the smartphone browser. do you any suggestion for this?

Comment: I am sorry I have limited knowledge on the matter.